# Custom permalink /%category%/%postname%/ produces 404 on each post

Tags: categories, permalinks, 404-error

I have installed brand-new *wordpress-4.8.3*. My next steps were, as in [WPBegginer - 
How to Include Category and Subcategory in WordPress URLs](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-include-category-and-subcategory-in-wordpress-urls/):

1. In *Dashboard/Settings/Permalinks*, I've pasted: `/%category%/%postname%/`;
2. Saved my permalinks settings;
3. Edited & Published my *"Hello World!"* post;
4. Visited *http://localhost/wordpress/uncategorized/hello-world/*
5. Got:

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /wordpress/uncategorized/hello-world/ was not found on this server.
>
> ---
>
> *Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80*

Bear in mind, it is brand-new fresh WordPress installation.

Then I've tried the hack with saving `.` (the dot character) as *Category base* inside *Dashboard/Settings/Permalinks* but it did not help. I want my permalinks to be structured like this:

*http://example.com/category/subcategory/postname*

How do I do that?

---

**EDIT**

If I save *Custom structure* as `/index.php/%category%/%postname%/` it **does work**, giving me *http://localhost/wordpress/uncategorized/hello-world/* in my post edit mode, with editable *hello-world* part. However, I do not want the `index.php` part in my permalink

Comment: I'm sure "the dot thing" does not work in WordPress 4+.

Comment: Does Wordpress show you the right permalink (like you expect)  when you are in post edit mode?

Comment: Yes it does, which in my case is _http://localhost/wordpress/uncategorized/hello-world/_

Comment: You’re seeing your server’s 404, not the WordPress theme 404, which means those requests aren’t being routed to WP. Does your server have mod_rewrite, and is it parsing htaccess files in your site’s root?